# List of list of dictionaries is updating top level entries

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list called `trips` which contains lists of `trip` which are in turn dictionaries of `leg`s.
So for instance there are 4 legs in a trip, and there hundreds of `trip` in `trips`.

When generating `trip` entries, I use the previous one and just update `leg_date` and then append that `trip` to `trips`.

However, when I change the `leg_date` entry in `trip`, it automagically changes the `leg_date` value in the previous `trip` that I had just appended to `trips`.
In other words, when I change `trip` it's also changing `trips`. It's almost as if `trips` contains pointers to `trip`.

I would expect the output to have `leg_date`s of `7/7` and `7/8` for the first entry and `7/14` and `7/15` for the second.  Instead I get both entries having `leg_date`s of `7/14` and `7/15`.

Output:

```
[[{'leg_date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 14), 'item2': 'green'},  
{'leg_date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 15), 'item2': 'red'}],  
[{'leg_date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 14), 'item2': 'green'},  
{'leg_date': datetime.date(2020, 7, 15), 'item2': 'red'}]]
```

Sample code:

```
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

trip = []
trips = []

trip_day = [1, 2]
bd_year = '2020'
bd_start_mo = 7
leg_dates = []
days = [7, 14]

leg1 = {'leg_date': '2020-07-07', 'item2': 'green'}
leg2 = {'leg_date': '2020-07-07', 'item2': 'red'}
trip = [leg1, leg2]

for idx,day in enumerate(days): # loop thru each instance of trip 
    for leg in trip_day: # loop thru each leg in a trip
        # build list of actual dates for each leg
        leg_dates.append(date(int(bd_year), bd_start_mo, day) + timedelta(days = (leg - 1)))
    for leg in range(0,len(trip_day)): # loop thru each leg and update actual date in the dict
        trip[leg]['leg_date'] = leg_dates[leg]

    trips.append(trip)
    print(trips)
    leg_dates = []
  #  trip = [leg1, leg2]
```

Comment: "It's almost as if "trips" contains pointers to trip" - you are right

Comment: "The below code will not run for you as there are over 400 lines of code with non public info.": make an mcve please

Comment: ""It's almost as if "trips" contains pointers to trip" - you are right – rdas"  But I used the .append method to add trip to trips which is a list of dictionaries.  Doesn't "append" just add the values and not add a reference?